# UITableView multiple row updates: inserts+removes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to make a chat using `UITableView`. New messages keep appearing from the bottom (table is rotated 180 as usual for these cases) - let's call this operation `insertion`. Also some messages which are already in the table should be updated - status change, text edits, etc... Let's call this one `edit`.

So, for `insertion`, I use `tableView.insertRows(at...` with `.top` animation type (because table is upside down) to make the cell "slide" from outside of the screen. And `edit` is a `deleteRows` followed by `insertRows` both with no animation, it just needs to stay in place and just update its "insides". All of this is happening in a same `tableView.beginUpdates()` `tableView.endUpdates()` block.

The problem is the unwanted animation for some of the `edits`. I've put together a simple chat imitation project. The app inserts new message every 3 seconds, and also changes the color of two previous messages. So `UITableView` has to do two `edit`s and one `insert` in one go. Here are the frames of a video of the issue (can't attach a video here):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Maybe that's the intended behaviour, but it looks bad I think. What I want to happen is for the `insert`ed message to slide from the bottom, and both `edit`s to just stay in their respective places, only moving up during the `insertion` with the rest of table content, like all non edited cells. Please help if you guys have any experience with this.

Here is the project: https://github.com/f3dm76/TableIssueExample

The video is in the readme of the project.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the unwanted animation for `edits` you can change logic behind  this action.
Instead of doing `deleteRows` + `insertRows` you can modify data source for these rows (corresponding item in `models` array). Then `tableView.reloadRows(for:)` should do all the work by itself (and set animation to `.automatic` for UIKit to figure it out by itself)
Also, documentation suggests using `tableView.performBatchUpdates()` instead of `begin`/`end`, I think there's something to do with animations sync (as in your case).

See the fixed version below:

```
// animate insertions and removals, but not edits
    tableView.performBatchUpdates {
        for change in dif {
            switch change {
            case let .remove(offset, model, _):
                let isEdit = editIds.contains(model.id)
                print("removal", isEdit ? "edit" : "", offset, model.property, model.text.prefix(10))
                if isEdit {
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: offset, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                } else {   
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: offset, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                }
            case let .insert(offset, model, _):
                let isEdit = editIds.contains(model.id)
                print("insertion", isEdit ? "edit" : "", offset, model.property, model.text.prefix(10))
                
                if !isEdit {
                    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: offset, section: 0)], with: .top)
                }
            }
        }
        print()
    }
```

Comment: But then the insertion won't get animated either

Comment: @f3dm76 your can do insert in the `tableView.beginUpdates()` - `tableView.endUpdates()` block after `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: reloadData messes with current offset too much, I ended up splitting all the updates into inserts and updates (which I tried to avoid), then using reloadRows for updates, and on completion of that - insertRows for insertions. It's long and ugly and has to use semaphores, I'd thought iOS table had a better way(

Comment: @f3dm76 updated the answer, the issue with animations should be gone

Comment: animation is not fixed in your code, I attached updated gif to example project. It's a bit different but still no good. I ended up manually splitting insertions and updates, applying updates with unanimated reloadData, and then calling insertRows for insertions.